# How to Migrate a windows phone app(8.1 XAML) which is live in windows store to 8.1 Silverlight?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have an app which is already available in windows store, which is written in 8.1 XAML. Due to some compatibility issue in the XAML version we have re-written the app in 8.1 SilverLight.

But, now the problem is I am not able to upload the silverlight app package to the windows store as an update to the existing app. How can I do that?

UPDATE: the actual problem is not when packaging, I have successfully packaged the new silverlight version of the app to an XAP file. The issue raises when I try to upload to the store website, It is not allowing me to submit an XAP file instead if Appx package, as I already have a live version with Appx package. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented limitation. You can't go backwards from an Appx to a Xap. See [Guidance for app package management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188601.aspx#phone)

> When an app has a published Windows Phone 8.1 .appx, subsequent
>   updates must either have a Windows Phone 8.1 .appx or Windows Phone
>   8.1 .appxbundle. In other words, a Windows Phone 8.1 XAP is not allowed. This applies to an .appxupload that contains a Windows Phone
>   8.1 .appx as well.

Comment: is there any option to convert an xap package to appx package? In the latest update the main change is related to Ad provider, we are moving to Admob, But we didn't find any option to add admob to 8.1 XAML app. any suggestions for that?

Comment: It's not a straight re-package. You'd have to port the code used in the app. Silverlight apps use Xap files. Windows Runtime apps use Appx files. From a quick search, AdMob doesn't support WinRt apps and so would need to be replaced with a different Ad package for use in an Appx.

Comment: you mean, a different ad provider or any other package that supports admob? If so, do you know any packages that I can use to display admob ads?

Answer (score 3):

There may be couple of reasons behind this.

XAML apps (Runtime) have Appx as app package where as Silverlight apps have XAP  as app package. There is difference between both the types of apps. Refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx).

Windows Phone Silverlight apps can’t be packaged by using this wizard. Only XAML/RT apps can be packaged. So if you have associated you RT app to store using Visual Studio then it may create a problem. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh975357.aspx).

Third possible reference may be, version number of packages. App Store does not allow equal or less version number than last uploaded app package. So check your app package version numbers.

Comment: the actual problem is not when packaging, I have successfully packaged the new silverlight version of the app to an XAP file. The issue raises when I try to upload to the store website, It is not allowing me to submit an XAP file instead if Appx package, as I already have a live version with Appx package. How can I solve this? Updating the question as well.

Comment: That could be a reason. Earlier it was runtime app and now it is silverlight app. Just try to create new app and see if it is uploading or not?

Comment: new app is working fine, but I am not able to update existing store app.